# Wordpress Add_filter Priority Issue On 2 Different Custom Plugins (Metaboxes)

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes, add-filter

I recently developed 2 seperate wordpress plugins for one of my projects

1. Partners
2. Resource Library

Both plugins create custom post types `fsb_partners` and `fsb_resource_library`. And in both plugins I have created different metaboxes (partners plugin metabox contains one file field i.e. Logo and resource library plugin creates metabox with two file fields i.e. Audio and PDF).

I used following code to create metabox in each plugin:

`add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', array($this, "fsb_partners_metaboxes"), 999);` ---> Partners Plugin

`add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', array($this, "fsb_resource_library_metaboxes"), 999);` ---> Resource Library Plugin

Now only metabox at resource library plugin is visible and other is not. If I change the priority of partner plugin metabox to `9999` then it shows up but at the same time resource library plugins goes off.

I know it's wordpress's `add_filter` hook's priority issue, but am unable to get hands on it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself. Just created a separate (common) function in my theme's `functions.php` as follows:

```
add_filter('cmb_meta_boxes', function( array $metaboxes = array() ) {

    global $fsb_resource_library, $fsb_partner;

    if( class_exists('fsb_resource_library') && is_object($fsb_resource_library) ) {
        $metaboxes += $fsb_resource_library->fsb_resource_library_metaboxes();  
    }

    if( class_exists('fsb_partners') && is_object($fsb_partner) ) {
        $metaboxes += $fsb_partner->fsb_partners_metaboxes();   
    }

    return $metaboxes;

});
```